# MATLAB Error: Bad property value found

Tags: matlab-figure

I am using Matlab R2014a.
Following is my code along with the error.

```
IterationColor = {'[0.0 0.0 0.0]',...
                  '[1.0 0.0 0.8]',...
                  '[0.2 0.0 1.0]',...
                  '[1.0 0.6 0.0]',...
                  '[0.2 0.4 0.0]',...
                  '[0.6 0.0 0.6]',...
                  '[1.0 0.0 0.0]',...
                  '[0.6 0.6 0.6]'};
IterationMarker = {'>','o','s','<','s','p','*','>','o','d'};

semilogy(x,y,'marker',IterationMarker{3},'color',IterationColor{8},'LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor',IterationColor{8},'MarkerFaceColor','[0 1 0]','MarkerSize',5);

Error using semilogy
Bad property value found.
Object Name: line
Property Name: 'Color'.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error and would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colour matrices aren't matrices, they're strings.
Remove the quotes around them in your cell definition.